# Not able to use Nullable DbGeography

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a geography field in SQL which I marked as null.

Then on my EF Entity I added a nullable `DbGeography?` property but I get a message saying that is not allowed.

So, how can I insert in the database a DbGeography that is not defined?

I was looking for something like DbGeography.Empty or DbGeography.Unknown.

But I wasn't able to find any ...

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: DbGeography is a class right? It's nullable already. No need for the `?`.

Answer (score 2):

DbGeography is a class so it is already nullable.  Just give it a null value in your model.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a non-null-able `DbGeography` property, but wanted to express an empty (but not null) value, you could do this...

```
[Required] public virtual DbGeography GpsCoordsOrWhatever { get; set; } = DbGeography.FromText("POINT EMPTY")
```

`DbGeography` and the other types in the `System.Data.Entity.Spatial` namespace are classes (reference types and therefore null-able).

Conversely, if you wanted to have a non-null-able property of class-type you would apply the `[Required]` attribute to the property, or use `modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().Property(t => t.Property).IsRequired()`. This doesn't prevent `null` assignment to the property, but it will be mapped to a non-null-able field in the backing store (database in most cases) and will be checked for `null` in Entity Framework's validation.

Comment: This is a very good point, as this can be used as an initializer for fields. You can avoid the nasty 'null'. Structures usually have a xxx.Empty field for same, and class' instances can be set by using 'new', but DbGeography doesn't has a default ctor and hence the answer is very good.

Answer (score 0):

This is because [DbGeography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography.aspx) is class and it is not allowed to have mark classes as `nullable`(the `nullable` thing is only for structures).

Change type of your property to `DbGeography`(not `DbGeography?`). As [DbGeography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography.aspx) is class it is ok for property to have `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

Entities don't need to be explicitly marked as nullable. You will be able to set it to null anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You would able to do `MyDbGeographyProperty = null;` Latitude and Longitude is read-only from the obj
Which is what kjbartel stated;